# Azure FileShare: The specified resource does not exist - SAS Authentication

Tags: java, scala, azure, azure-storage-files, azure-sas

I am trying to list files under an Azure FileShare using a SAS in Java/ Scala.

I do not have access to Storage Account, but only a SAS key for a particular share in Azure File Storage. How to directly access the Share  in Java?

I am able to list the directories and files in the Share using Storage Explorer, download using AZCopy or Rest Call using the share url with SAS key.

Almost everyone else posting with similar error has tried to authenticate using Storage Account Keys and for BlobStorage. They seem to have access to one level above the share, i.e the storage account. But I need to directly connect to the FileShare using SAS that works only for this share.

```
  val storageConnectionString =
  s"FileEndpoint=$endpoint;" + // https://xyz.file.core.windows.net
    "SharedAccessSignature=" +
    URLEncoder.encode(sas)

  val storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString)

  val fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient()
  val share = fileClient.getShareReference(fshare)  //A fileshare with access
  val rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference()
  val files = rootDir.listFilesAndDirectories()

  files.forEach(file => println(file.getUri)) //Error: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The specified resource does not exist.
```

The files in the Share are visible in UI of Storage Explorer using the same URI(FileShareEndpoint+"/"+fshare+"?"+sas).

Expected to get a list of files and directories but getting exception: "The specified resource does not exist.". Is it the code or is it not possible through a program to connect to the share without first authenticating to the storage account?

Comment: What kind of permission you have in your shared access signature?

Comment: sr=s which I guess is for all folders & files within the share.

Comment: Can you share your complete SAS token? You can get rid of `sig` portion when sharing.

Comment: sv=2018-03-28&si=abc&sr=s&sig=

Comment: Oh, you're using a shared access policy (`si`). Can you share the permissions defined in that policy?

Comment: The value of si is the company name. I guess only the provider of SAS knows the mapping assigned to it.

Comment: You would need to ask the permissions included in the access policy from the person who gave you this SAS token. Please ask that person if `List` permission is included there or not. For listing files, you would need this permission. HTH.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav. Will reach out to person who gave SAS and try to get the required permissions. Also, is the code snippet correct and is listing fileshares using shared access keys supported through REST? I noticed somewhere that listing is supported only for Blob containers using REST.

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. I believe the issue is with the permissions in your SAS token.